# Need a Extract XPath help on an Email using webhook.site

Tags: xpath, extract, webhooks, email-parsing

I am needing to extract specific lines from a raw email that i have coming into my webhook.site url. I figured it would be an xpath extract or some custom action but my knowledge only goes so far.
i need to extract: Subject: which is the header about the content-type: text/plain.
Whats my path and layout to do so??
thanks

```
Return-Path: <leadnotification-noreply2@ylopo.com>
Received: from mail-lf1-f53.google.com (mail-lf1-f53.google.com [209.85.167.53])
 by inbound-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com with SMTP id nqoso8q41s14sho14modqhpqbqvvvcqb0e3hea81
 for OsirsYlopoPriorityEmail@email.webhook.site;
 Wed, 27 Oct 2021 19:21:34 +0000 (UTC)
X-SES-Spam-Verdict: PASS
X-SES-Virus-Verdict: PASS
Received-SPF: pass (spfCheck: domain of ylopo.com designates 209.85.167.53 as permitted sender) client-ip=209.85.167.53; envelope-from=leadnotification-noreply2@ylopo.com; helo=mail-lf1-f53.google.com;
Authentication-Results: amazonses.com;
 spf=pass (spfCheck: domain of ylopo.com designates 209.85.167.53 as permitted sender) client-ip=209.85.167.53; envelope-from=leadnotification-noreply2@ylopo.com; helo=mail-lf1-f53.google.com;
 dkim=pass header.i=@ylopo.com;
 dmarc=pass header.from=ylopo.com;
X-SES-RECEIPT: AEFBQUFBQUFBQUFHdlpaMkNVNS9wd25QYmtqSU9xbGJBVzZJa0tSV1dCNWcwWFFwZFNUS1lweHpxY1A1NlRoSlZyU1NEM0drMlp3Q0Jpd0d2ZG1RUC9VYVRCbWt6UUhMdkFwOUJLS1NGYnFCSzQyVGpQK1loZzU0SkpIcy9pNnQ4aHhScnV2dG9sV2M5b2VnSzY4MU0vMm9JaWx5VDJOcW5WWllPRzhvNkp6VHdJSWNmbmJBd1lvZlF1WHdEQUNFRzkyM0dQQVkxdGgwS0NwUHAzcVo5dit5clgvOXFzdG8xMFJaTVpuMVRLcXUwVDNNMVRod3lWSDB0NStRNjNUcEMrZ2RwZ0dSZFBQcEQ2OXZ2bUFOMkI3UUhJYUNZdG5iM2hqMUZhV1NST0FBbHdwSUM5TDIySk11dWh2alN3VE9BbVhGWjlKditMUzQ9
X-SES-DKIM-SIGNATURE: a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; b=AXzUmXzoB1/c89r/6eJBBuEUriK6kdQMMJRXPnBwlUC5oCKD1Apk+Av3zpg5yxj+4djsbxeCsSPIwkcYX6xlXUfWUQ/mi7pgHViuVh+r/NrEKptMjb5efdeH7/mls8tRzyaQQF+12LbSb0wBo2bTkcQLXkP3WvKP5OSFde3B620=; c=relaxed/simple; s=uku4taia5b5tsbglxyj6zym32efj7xqv; d=amazonses.com; t=1635362495; v=1; bh=5WqfRbOb11+ge2mx0Egi4AqA6n1lyVIU1IpAVg4H0dA=; h=From:To:Cc:Bcc:Subject:Date:Message-ID:MIME-Version:Content-Type:X-SES-RECEIPT;
Received: by mail-lf1-f53.google.com with SMTP id y26so8295478lfa.11
        for <OsirsYlopoPriorityEmail@email.webhook.site>; Wed, 27 Oct 2021 12:21:34 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=ylopo.com; s=google;
        h=mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to;
        bh=nrZwBjOzEgZN0tQ61MtDEDWEj3XJn2q+y4Qx1/acY5A=;
        b=gtj7GzFH9q0O2S1ynt3Qvhp5zgomrYmufqbSQ0qIjEalwk9Dd0lSI7MeOMrgNtjDFL
         sGwRBO9L4ZW3yE5ZKmP/wSYKmVlerL51ZlTQQhuTXsxioymJto3j0ERWirJQj+BapzGT
         HBxScQEwYkpqZqWX6KkCTjCzCGZqW+fp9vitHmgfqt1/nLiyZp+7WEbluw+rPQO0G7dR
         CGObjTeYa0Fd+Dc8h/k/a7suZ2umrqqnl/HYaoY7BeMxhAJDP5TuaoAsjQh1EU9zqHY8
         TJxcJZoo83n+7f8qVMSNpAstVynlmsH6h7nzW1q27pfeWWY6LgMRUjkKqrYIc4F8lsqR
         98SQ==
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=1e100.net; s=20210112;
        h=x-gm-message-state:mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to;
        bh=nrZwBjOzEgZN0tQ61MtDEDWEj3XJn2q+y4Qx1/acY5A=;
        b=D/VtUGyzcVfTxi2x63V/3OC7ckHj1uuLlILVUNmOkMrvW6GWUJq7mKI9/D4UYXWc5i
         Ybds0/Dktx6cDJUZbAiAYWOiYd56XMMc2O+Yoe36u+eREry29IJQXOLTcRj2KFcLGSWa
         Me5GjcFPVBTuhjtxlPb41wCKhGmDevYEHDkbGIcoNp5w3weGobSPg8bLQNsEO/Hspn6y
         4Q18s7uNIJ8X2o5DEevA8DrZfibThQ3X5HUFmpuaRT3089Qm3H92wiHv3rkn3fQFDnVY
         4p/PcWw9bxK6pU47bBtO/qtJ2ce/3Q7OQq/NCvJ5ZjD83lRai1mKIaCtiyt3gccQrd5S
         hc5g==
X-Gm-Message-State: AOAM531woVO34G4bG9aVBLV9ae6QgX8pklYV4DDYs4VALPxuz7W9GStL
    QM3YDolGrDOXbzaZghT/1+So8DR3WqejlOCELMsa+zO2Xxs=
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ABdhPJylxjs2zEdxsuBr2M1l9CnsOHrWvk+53vOLw2bs77bdl75s4022uZaKlqYx/GG+UyEsRrt8DT6mRRCAQZSebbE=
X-Received: by 2002:a05:6512:acf:: with SMTP id n15mr578213lfu.222.1635362493750;
 Wed, 27 Oct 2021 12:21:33 -0700 (PDT)
Received: from 927538837578 named unknown by gmailapi.google.com with
 HTTPREST; Wed, 27 Oct 2021 12:21:33 -0700
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: leadnotification-noreply2@ylopo.com
Date: Wed, 27 Oct 2021 12:21:33 -0700
Message-ID: <CAN2r-3o0aD_98y2GrdxdBW7W6UHi8RMS9-JmvsHrftheurwMeQ@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Ylopo Priority Alert - Party: Daniel Askew 19293 -
 PRIORITY_LEAD_EVENT - massaquoimartha@yahoo.com - 8562838525
To: OsirsYlopoPriorityEmail@email.webhook.site, qojfsghi@mailparser.io
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="00000000000084f8be05cf5a80dc"

--00000000000084f8be05cf5a80dc
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

Lead Name: Martha Mansaray
Lead Email: massaquoimartha@yahoo.com
Lead Phone: 8562838525
Text:

Ylopo PRIORITY LEAD ALERT: Martha Mansaray (856) 283-8525

Martha Mansaray VIEWED 6185 Old Highway 31E, Bethpage, TN
<https://andrea.livetn.com/listing-detail/124037148> 29 TIMES.

Recommend actions:
```

Comment: XPath, by definition is, used for selecting nodes from an XML document.  Your content is not XML.  Why did you choose XPath?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need regex because XPath is used to find a node from XML/HTML type text. But regex can be used on any text. To get the value of header name "Subject" you can use regex `\nSubject: (.*)`.

Python example:

```
import re
sample = """
...
<text you want to parse>
...
Subject: Ylopo Priority Alert - Party: Daniel Askew 19293 -
"""
if match := re.search(r"\nSubject: (.*)", sample):
    print(match.group(1))  # output: Ylopo Priority Alert - Party: Daniel Askew 19293 -
```